# Where does an APN profile get saved in your iphone?

Tags: iphone

I'm wanting to view an existing profile that I have already installed on my iphone. I wanted to know where and how can i view the details?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps it's a keychain entry somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such term as APN profile. There is provision profiles and there is APN certificates that embedded into provisioning profiles. You can check list of all provisioning profiles in Settings -> General -> Profiles. You will be able to get a minimal information about required provisioning profiles such as when it received and expires. You will also be able to remove it if you want. They do not provide any specific information related to APN through this UI.

Answer (score 0):

In device , you can see it in

**Settings->General->Profiles**

In development system, You can see it in **Keychain**

Open the **Finder->Applications->Keychain**

In key chain you can use search option and use the searching string as "iphone".

You can see the installed provisioning profiles under **Xcode->window->Organizer->Devices**

Comment: Well the thing is that I need to be able to install a configuration profile on an another device. There is not a way for me to save the profile and/or view details so I'm able to create my own profile.

Comment: "I need to be able to install a configuration profile on an another device" Could please explain this ?

Comment: I have the profile installed in one device and I would like to be able to send it to another one. How would I be able to do so?

Comment: u want to install one profile from devide1 to device2 ? is device2 device-id mentioned in profile ?